# To query from different models and to arrange the properties in the json body

Tags: json, laravel, api

I have an api call function below to create a summary of students based on their attendance status but I am failing to structure the JSON response body based on want I want to display because it fetching the model first

```
//attendance_id = 1 it means Present if 2 it means Absent
  public function getAttendanceReport($grade_id, $date){
       $attendance_fetched_present = AttendanceStudent::where('created_at', 'LIKE', $date.'%')
                                    ->where('grade_id', $grade_id)
                                    ->where('attendance_id' , "1")
                                    ->addSelect([
                            'total_present_student' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
                                    ->whereIn(
                                    'student_id',
                                    Student::select('id')),
                            'total_present_boys' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
                                    ->whereRaw('gender = "male"')
                                    ->whereIn(
                                    'student_id',
                                    Student::select('id')),
                            'total_present_girls' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
                                    ->whereRaw('gender = "female"')
                                    ->whereIn(
                                    'student_id',
                                    Student::select('id'))
                                    ])->get();

       $attendance_fetched_absent = AttendanceStudent::where('created_at', 'LIKE', $date.'%')
                                    ->where('grade_id', $grade_id)
                                    ->where('attendance_id' , "2")
                                    ->addSelect([
                            'total_absent_student' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
                                     ->whereIn(
                                         'student_id',
                                         Student::select('id')),
                            'total_absent_boys' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
                                    ->whereRaw('gender = "male"')
                                    ->whereIn(
                                         'student_id',
                                         Student::select('id')),
                            'total_absent_girls' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
                                    ->whereRaw('gender = "female"')
                                    ->whereIn(
                                         'student_id',
                                         Student::select('id'))
                                         ])->get();

                        return response()->json(['message'=>'Attendance Report in Grade',
                                                 'Present' => $attendance_fetched_present,
                                                 'Absent' => $attendance_fetched_absent ]);
                                    }
```

the json body I am getting is not the one i want

```
{
    "message": "Attendance Report in Grade",
    "Present": [
        {
            "attendance_id": 1,
            "student_id": 1,
            "grade_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-06-17T04:02:41.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-06-17T04:02:41.000000Z",
            "total_present_student": 16,
            "total_present_boys": 9,
            "total_present_girls": 7
        },
        {
            "attendance_id": 1,
            "student_id": 2,
            "grade_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-06-17T04:02:41.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-06-17T04:02:41.000000Z",
            "total_present_student": 16,
            "total_present_boys": 9,
            "total_present_girls": 7
        },
],
    "Absent": [
        {
            "attendance_id": 2,
            "student_id": 16,
            "grade_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-06-17T04:17:12.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-06-17T04:17:12.000000Z",
            "total_absent_student": 16,
            "total_absent_boys": 9,
            "total_absent_girls": 7
        }
    ]
}
```

The json body i want is the one below

```
{
    "message": "attendance report",
    "Present": 
        {
            "total_present_students": 10,
            "total_boys_present": 5,
            "total_girls_present": 5,
            "created_at": "2022-06-04T14:41:34.000000Z"
        },
    "Absent":
        {
            
            "total_present_students": 12,
            "total_boys_present": 5,
            "total_girls_present": 5,
            "created_at": "2022-06-04T14:41:34.000000Z"
        },
    "total_students_in_grade": 22
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using laravel [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) you can:

1. get rid of dozens requests (top level `foreach` loops getting student data)
2. make code a lot more readable
3. take advantage of laravel's [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#main-content) fluent methods

if you didn't create [one-to-one](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship) relation between `AttendanceStudent` and `Student` models then its time to

```php
// AttendanceStudent model
public function student(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
}
```

```php
// controller
public function getAttendanceReport($grade_id, $date)
{
  // here you have the global collection that can be filtered explicitly with students data
  $attendanceFetched = AttendanceStudent::where('created_at', 'LIKE', "$date%")
    ->with('student') // eager loading student for each attendance record
    ->where('grade_id', $grade_id)->get();

  //now you can filter collection even by inner objects

  // no additional requests here
  $totalCount = $attendanceFetched->count();

  $presentCount = $attendanceFetched->where('attendance_id', 1)->count();
  $presentBoysCount = $attendanceFetched->where('attendance_id', 1)
    ->where('student.gender', 'male')
    ->count();
  $presentGirlsCount = $attendanceFetched->where('attendance_id', 1)
    ->where('student.gender', 'female')
    ->count();

  $absentCount = $attendanceFetched->where('attendance_id', 2)->count();
  $absentBoysCount = $attendanceFetched->where('attendance_id', 2)
    ->where('student.gender', 'male')
    ->count();
  $absentGirlsCount = $attendanceFetched->where('attendance_id', 2)
    ->where('student.gender', 'female')
    ->count();

  return response()->json([
    'message' => 'Attendance Report in Grade',
    'Total Students' => $totalCount,
    'Present' => $presentCount,
    'Total_boys_present' => $presentBoysCount,
    'Total_girls_present' => $presentGirlsCount,
    'Absent' => $absentCount,
    'Total_boys_absent' => $absentBoysCount,
    'Total_girls_absent' => $absentGirlsCount
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I think is that you select all the contents from the tables, So what to do is to iterate throughout the selected eloquent and then select what you wish to get in the Created array then return as following:

```
public function getAttendanceReport($grade_id, $date){
   $attendance_fetched_present = AttendanceStudent::where('created_at', 'LIKE', $date.'%')
                                ->where('grade_id', $grade_id)
                                ->where('attendance_id' , "1")
                                ->addSelect([
                        'total_present_student' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
                                ->whereIn(
                                'student_id',
                                Student::select('id')),
                        'total_present_boys' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
                                ->whereRaw('gender = "male"')
                                ->whereIn(
                                'student_id',
                                Student::select('id')),
                        'total_present_girls' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
                                ->whereRaw('gender = "female"')
                                ->whereIn(
                                'student_id',
                                Student::select('id'))
                                ])->get();

   $attendance_fetched_absent = AttendanceStudent::where('created_at', 'LIKE', $date.'%')
                                ->where('grade_id', $grade_id)
                                ->where('attendance_id' , "2")
                                ->addSelect([
                        'total_absent_student' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
                                 ->whereIn(
                                     'student_id',
                                     Student::select('id')),
                        'total_absent_boys' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
                                ->whereRaw('gender = "male"')
                                ->whereIn(
                                     'student_id',
                                     Student::select('id')),
                        'total_absent_girls' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
                                ->whereRaw('gender = "female"')
                                ->whereIn(
                                     'student_id',
                                     Student::select('id'))
                                     ])->get();
                                     
    $present_student_arr = [];
    $absent_student_arr = [];

    foreach ($attendance_fetched_present as $present) {
        $present_student_arr[] = array(
            'total_present_students' => $present['total_present_student'],
            'total_boys_present' => $present['total_present_boys'],
            'total_girls_present' => $present['total_present_girls'],
            'created_at' => $present['created_at'],
        );
    }

    foreach ($attendance_fetched_absent as $absent) {
        $absent_student_arr[] = array(
            'total_absent_students' => $absent['total_absent_student'],
            'total_boys_absent' => $absent['total_absent_boys'],
            'total_girls_absent' => $absent['total_absent_girls'],
            'created_at' => $present['created_at'],
        );
    }



    return response()->json(['message'=>'Attendance Report in Grade',
                                             'Present' => $present_student_arr,
                                             'Absent' => $absent_student_arr ]);
```

}

Comment: Hope it will help.

Comment: yeah it provided me with some help but still in query data it didn't